# For...in performance in Delphi?

Tags: performance, delphi, loops

How does the performance of Delphi for...in loops compare to traditional for 1 to N loops?

Is it simply syntactic sugar that makes your code easier to read/potentially less buggy since it lacks loops counter variables that could be off by one? Or are there actual performance benefits you gain as well (eg: pipelining or multithreading) since the results of individual loop iterations are not guaranteed to be calculated in a specific order?

Comment: It depends on how the enumerator is implemented. And it depends on what is inside the loop. As for ordering, it is generally well defined. I've never seen an enumerator what does not have a well defined ordering.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Don't forget there is a try-finally that the compiler inserts around the for..in but is slightly out side the scope (but I think it is worth mentioning).

Comment: @Nicholas Not necessarily. Only if the enumerator needs lifetime management. Not for enumerators implemented as records. Which is the most efficient. But Embarcadero devs don't seem to understand that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Don't records lifetime management via the compiler and as such, the compiler will put in a try-finally to decrement the reference count accordingly?

Comment: @NicholasRing That would happen if the record in question contained managed types. There's no need for it to do so.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But wouldn't the compiler need to put some code in to release the memory of the record (if the reference count hits zero), even if it doesn't have managed types?

Comment: @NicholasRing Records that don't contain managed types are not reference counted. Also, why did you delete you other question after I had spent the time to answer it? That seems rude.

Answer (score 2):

[Stefan Glienke](http://stackoverflow.com/users/587106/stefan-glienke) posted about loop performance measuring in his [blog](https://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2018/07/loop-wars-measuring-performance.html).

TL;DR:

- Performance of classic for-loop and for-in-loop is almost the same (after some optimizations)
- > [...] the compiler generates terrible code when you are using inline with managed function results [...]
- > Some code in the RTL is far from being ideal
- > The 32-bit compiler has much room for optimization